# Select one of two different methods in a method chain in C#

Tags: c#, delegation

Consider the following code:

```
decimal userPrice = product.Status == ProductStatusEnum.Presale
   ? pricingHelper.GetUserPresalePricing(sku, user).UserCustomPrice
   : pricingHelper.GetUserProductPricing(sku, user).UserCustomPrice;
```

Is there some way to place the expression that determines which method to use inside the method chain instead of having to use two complete method chains? My mind goes to the use of a delegate or perhaps calling by name using reflection, but neither of those strike me as reasonable solutions (especially the calling by name).

I realize in this case that the method chain is not long (there's just one property afterward), but imagine a scenario with a much longer method chain. I *like* method chaining over creating a lot of variables, however, for clarity, in a long method chain having a difference in method usage like this, I'd choose temporary storage in a variable over repeating myself. But does it have to be that way?

In javascript this would be quite simple:

```js
var userPrice = pricingHelper[
   product.Status === ProductStatusEnum.Presale
   ? GetUserPresalePricing
   : GetUserProductPricing
](sku, user).UserCustomPrice;
```

Also, perhaps placing one of the two methods into a variable and then using that variable, as in (bad pseudocode):

```
SomeDelegate = product.Status == ProductStatusEnum.Presale
   ? pricingHelper.GetUserPresalePricing
   : pricingHelper.GetUserProductPricing;

decimal userPrice = SomeDelegate(sku, user).UserCustomPrice;
```

Given that C# can do most things that functional languages can, there has to be a way (not saying it's necessarily better than the starting code above, just wondering).

Your comments on whether such a construction is useful or clearer than the original code are also welcome.

One more thought comes to mind, which is that in the `pricingHelper` class, I could create a `GetUserPricing` method that takes a parameter indicating whether to get the presale or product pricing. Hmmm...

Comment: I like the last one for a long string of properties, but this is going to be pretty opinion based. Perhaps this is better on CodeReview?

Comment: About method chaining - [Train Wreck Anti Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TrainWreck). Also its hell to unit-test such code

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy or also known as the [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) if you want the "this is a good idea" version instead of the "this is a bad idea" version

Comment: @ScottChamberlain good note :) But Method Chaining is just a technique used for implementing fluent interfaces. As Martin Fowler wrote, true fluency is much more than that.

Comment: Re: vote to close due to "opinion-based". Perhaps the part about whether such a construction is useful is opinion-based, but do you really think that the main question "how to not repeat the entire expression" doesn't have an objective answer?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I was in particular thinking of Linq where many method chains are reasonable. The Train Wreck anti-pattern is something I can wholeheartedly agree is best to avoid.

Comment: `One more thought comes to mind, which is that I could create a GetUserPricing method that takes a parameter indicating whether to get the presale or product pricing. Hmmm...`
No, one that takes `product` as a parameter. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var f = product.Status == ProductStatusEnum.Presale
   ? new Func<Sku, User, CustomPrice>(pricingHelper.GetUserPresalePricing)
   : pricingHelper.GetUserProductPricing;

decimal userPrice = f(user, price).UserCustomPrice;
```

Comment: You don't have to put the part after the colon inside a `new Func` as well?

Comment: @ErikE - I don't think so - there should be an implicit conversion from the method group to the given `Func` type.

Comment: You answered the question as asked--thank you! Ultimately, the correct thing to do in my specific codebase is to move the logic into the pricing web service where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

You have duplication in your code - getting of `UserCustomPrice` (or whatever you are 'chaining'). Why this happens? Because business logic of your method sounds like *get custom user price of whatever product pricing*. If you'll write down same requirements in code, it will look like

```
var productPricing = GetProductPricing(product, user, sku);
decimal userPrice = productPricing.UserCustomPrice;
```

With product pricing getting moved to separate method:

```
private IProductPricing GetProductPricing(Product product, User user, int sku)
{
    if (product.Status == ProductStatusEnum.Presale)
        return pricingHelper.GetUserPresalePricing(sku, user);

    return pricingHelper.GetUserProductPricing(sku, user);
}
```

Now intent is clear, especially comparing to JavaScript version.

Note: future refactoring can lead to moving `GetProductPricing` method to `pricingHelper`

Comment: This is a good observation, that if the product determines which price, then pass it in as a parameter. However, the sku fully implies the product, so there may be more refactoring possible. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Ultimately, the correct thing to do in my specific codebase is to move the logic into the pricing web service where it belongs. We'll probably tolerate the ugliness right now (not creating the method you suggested), but your feedback was helpful in pointing out the real underlying problem.